# Dynamic Div creation issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have issues create a new `<div>` tag using jQuery.

My requirements are:

1. Create div tag and its id dynamically
2. Provide the content between the `<div>` & `</div>` dynamically

below is the code snippet i tried

```
for (var i in List){
$('#count').append('<div id="content_'+i+'">')
.append(List[i]).append('</div>').append('<br />');
}
```

where List Object with Key and Value Pair

Output -

```
<div id="count" align="left">
<div id="content_4504"></div>Steve <br>
<div id="content_2024"></div>Richard <br>
</div>
```

what i need to display the Names inside the  tags.

Comment: Can we see your whole code? In the form of a jsfiddle perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way is to dynamically generate the HTML, try something like this instead:

```
for (var i in List){
$('#count').append('<div id="content_' + i + '">' + List[i] + '</div><br/>')
}
```

Comment: If you need to clear the content of #count, add $('#count').empty(); before the for loop.

Comment: It's just an idea @josh. No exact solution. General suggestion was to write full HTML instead.

Comment: As Josh mentioned, it is overwriting each loop content..!

Comment: Try append instead of HTML

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are appending strings to the `#count` element not the element that you created and appended it:

```
for (var i in List){
     $('<div id="content_'+i+'">')
              .text(List[i])
              .appendTo('#count')
              .after('<br/>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (var i in List){
    var divContent=$('<div />').attr({id:"content_"+i}).html(List[i]);
    $('#count').append(divContent,'<br>');
   ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i in List)
{
  var $dyn = $("<div></div>").attr({'id':'content_'+i}).text(List[i]);
  $('#count').append($dyn).append('<br>');
}
```

This should do it.